# Run custom command with modified files as arguments

Tags: cmake

For example, I have N files and a command that generates an output file from them. Then I, say, change `file32` and `file51`. Is it possible by means of CMake to make it so that now the command is executed as follows:

```
my-command file32 file51
```

Or at least

```
my-command file32 && my-command file51
```

As a generator, I can use Ninja or Make

Comment: Can you provide an MRE with actual and desired outputs? I think that would ground this discussion a bit. Help us understand what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kind of hack around this using a response file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test LANGUAGES NONE)

# Add a command for deleting the global response file
set(rsp "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my-command.rsp")
add_custom_target(delete-rsp COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E rm -f "${rsp}")

# Update timestamps for each file, adding it to the initially-empty RSP
set(stamps "")
foreach (i RANGE 1 100)
  list(APPEND stamps "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/stamp_${i}.out")
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "stamp_${i}.out"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E echo "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file${i}" >> "${rsp}"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E touch "stamp_${i}.out"
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file${i}"
  )
endforeach ()

add_custom_target(update-stamps DEPENDS ${stamps})
add_dependencies(update-stamps delete-rsp)

# Now run the actual command
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT "changed-list"
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E cat "${rsp}" | tee changed-list
  DEPENDS "${stamps}"
)

add_custom_target(run-my-command ALL DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/changed-list")
add_dependencies(run-my-command update-stamps)
```

This uses a series of empty stamp files to keep track of which files individually have been updated. These are attached to a custom target `update-stamps` that manages running two commands:

1. Update the stamp file
2. Add the changed file name to a "response file"

This custom target depends on another one that always deletes the response file at the start of the build. Therefore after the `update-stamps` target completes, the response file contains the exact list of files that have changed.

Finally, `run-my-command` simply prints out that list for demonstration.

---

Here's what I see (abridged) at the terminal:

```
$ ls
CMakeLists.txt
$ touch file{1..100}
$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  file13  file19 ...
...
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/build
$ cmake --build build --verbose
[1/102] cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f /path/to/build/my-command.rsp
[2/102] cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E echo /path/to/file16 >> /path/to/build/my-command.rsp && /usr/bin/cmake -E touch stamp_16.out
...
[102/102] cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cat /path/to/build/my-command.rsp | tee changed-list
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file16
/path/to/file13
...
/path/to/file99
$ touch file32 file51
$ cmake --build build --verbose
[1/4] cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f /path/to/build/my-command.rsp
[2/4] cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E echo /path/to/file32 >> /path/to/build/my-command.rsp && /usr/bin/cmake -E touch stamp_32.out
[3/4] cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E echo /path/to/file51 >> /path/to/build/my-command.rsp && /usr/bin/cmake -E touch stamp_51.out
[4/4] cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cat /path/to/build/my-command.rsp | tee changed-list
/path/to/file32
/path/to/file51
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that there isn't a simple directive for this like GNU Make's `$?` automatic variable